# XAMPP MySQL port 3306 keeps reseting itself

Tags: mysql, xampp, port

I am attempting to setup XAMPP on my PC, but I keep getting the famous:

```
17:07:22  [mysql]   Problem detected!
17:07:22  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by "D:\mysql\bin\mysqld MySQL"!
17:07:22  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
17:07:22  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
17:07:22  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
17:07:22  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

I have had mysql already installed on PC for educational purposes, and not it seems to create this problem.
I have tried:

- Renaming the ports in my.ini
- Checking the netstat, finding the PID and disabling it in the task manager
- Disabling the mySql in services
- Ending its process in the task manager

In the last three options, mysql would always turn itself back on whenever I tried to start it. I mean it's logical, but every time with that damn error.

So, does anybody know a way to fix this error?
And if not, anybody know a different soft to get me a localhost without many problems?

Comment: start > run > services.msc > find MySQL -> disable. You have MySQL that boots itself up every time you kill it in the task manager. Therefore your port is taken and the "new" MySQL can't use it.

Comment: This is because already had MySQL server installed on your machine and the port 3306 already being used by the Mysql, that's why you are unable to configure the MYSQL server which comes with XAMPP. To get round this problem, Just uninstall your old MYSQL server.

Comment: Could you not just configure XAMPP's MySQL to use a different port so it doesn't conflict with your default installation?

Comment: Disabled it, even set it to manual, and still the same. Switched enable type to "disabled" and when I start mysql it now just says "Attempting to start MySQL service..."

Comment: Hexana. Read the question, I already tried this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the running the installator again.

When using WAMP, whenever some weird/random configuration failed, usually running the installer with administrative rights fixed the issue.

However, on XAMP, some details may differ.
Check for the following service: xampmysqld64 kill that service. then restart your WAMP

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good tutorial by Rachel Andrew who recommends installing PuPHPet, VirtualBox and Vagrant to solve your development environment woes:

https://rachelandrew.co.uk/presentations/deploy/puphpet